# Scroll EditText in Android

Tags: android, text, widget, scroll

I have an EditText widget in my activity which contains large text ( say 2000 lines), I want to scroll easily and quickly by touching and dargging scrollbar thumb, but seems the scrollbar in android is not touchable, and fastScrollEnabled does not work on EditText.

Is there any subclass or extension of EditText which supports touchable vertical scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    mEtComments.setScroller(new Scroller(mContext));
    mEtComments.setMaxLines(10);
    mEtComments.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    mEtComments.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```